# How to Create flexible Rounded corners?

Tags: css, html

[image: Creating Flexible corner]

I want to Create DIV based Flexible corners. as per shown in the Image.
This is Not regular rounded corner, but something more complicated. This is Something like **challenge**  .

And Please **Note** that I want Image based rounded Corners, so please give answer as per requirments.

Thanks a Lot

Comment: Would I get shot if I suggested <table>s? ;)

Comment: @ricebowl still I am waiting for some Good triks , I will wait 48Hrs for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [The Thrashbox](http://www.vertexwerks.com/tests/sidebox/) approach for this.

Comment: @ddrace 
accepted Answer. 
If You like my Q. then please Vote Up.:)

Answer (score 5):

Well, the easiest answer is: use CSS3:

```
#roundedCornerDiv {
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;     /* for mozilla-based browsers */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;  /* for webkit-based browsers */
    border-radius: 1em;          /* theoretically for *all* browsers
                                    dependant on implementation of CSS3 */
    border: 12px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned these I always forget to use them when designing control panels that I don't want to flood with resources (round corner images ect.)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the requirement for image-based corners which...make life harder for yourself? Umm...'kay, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to do this with 9 explicitly sized and floated divs. the corner divs are fixed size and have background-url for the 4 corners and the side divs are repeat-y and top bottom divs have repeat-x

Answer (score 1):

You can use a series of spans and 4 images, one for each corner, to make a resizable rounded corner div.  Like this:

```
div {
    background: white url(topleft.gif) top left no-repeat;
}

div span {
    display: block;
    background: url(topright.gif) top right no-repeat;
}

div span span {
    background: url(bottomright.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
}

div span span span {
    padding: 2em;
    height: 0; /* fixes a padding bug in IE */
    background: url(bottomleft.gif) bottom left no-repeat;
}

div span span > span {
    height: auto; /* sets the height back to auto for all other browsers */
}
```

And now for the HTML:

```
<div><span><span><span>Round corners!</span></span></span></div>
```

For an actual example and code please refer to [this page](http://htmldog.com/examples/images3_3.html) for a working example and source code.

Comment: sadly this doesn't display properly on IE7 .. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

first is the left-upper corner.
second is the right-upper corner.
third is the right-lower corner.
fourth is the lower-left corner.

you can use that basically in any tag where you want the round corners. just remember to specify the border like:

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

if you specify the border separately, eg:

```
border-left: 6px;
border-right: 6px;
border-top: 2px;
border-bottom: 2px;
```

you can get some awesome-looking stuff.